# context.getBean throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. When I call `context.getBean(MyController.class)`, it works fine. When I call `context.getBean("MyController")` or `context.getBean("com.MyController")`, `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is thrown. How to get the bean with its name?

Application

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        // MyController myController = (MyController) context.getBean("com.MyController"); NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
        // MyController myController= (MyController) context.getBean("MyController"); NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
        MyController myController = (MyController) context.getBean(MyController.class); // works fine
        System.out.println(myService);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class MyController {
}
```

Comment: Try `context.getBean("myController")`.

Comment: @NiVeR it works, thank you

Comment: Np. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also define name of controller in your MyController class as below,

```
@Controller(value="MyController")
public class MyController {
}
```